# Foreign key in active record’s self-referential has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using rails 4 with schema_plus gem.

I want to be able to access models this way:

```
    phrase = Phrase.create(name:'car')
    another_phrase = Phrase.create(name:'vehicle')
    phrase.synonym_phrases << another_phrase
    p phrase.synonym_phrases
```

My relationship setup:

```
    class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :synonyms
      has_many :synonym_phrases, through: :synonyms
    end

    class Synonym < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :phrase
      belongs_to :synonym_phrase, class_name: 'Phrase', foreign_key: :synonym_id
    end
```

After migratind database, the generated schema looks like this:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141211103911) do

      create_table "phrases", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      create_table "synonyms", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "phrase_id"
        t.integer  "synonym_id"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.index ["phrase_id"], :name => "fk__synonyms_phrase_id"
        t.index ["synonym_id"], :name => "fk__synonyms_synonym_id"
        t.foreign_key ["phrase_id"], "phrases", ["id"], :on_update => :no_action, :on_delete => :no_action, :name => "fk_synonyms_phrase_id"
        t.foreign_key ["synonym_id"], "synonyms", ["id"], :on_update => :no_action, :on_delete => :no_action, :name => "fk_synonyms_synonym_id"
      end
```

In which the second foreign key assigment is wrong, because it points to synonyms table, instead pointing to phrases table (self-referentiall).

I found out, that adding `foreign_key: { references: :phrases }` to migration solves the problem.

```
    # db/migrate/20141211103911_create_synonyms.rb
    class CreateSynonyms < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :synonyms do |t|
          t.integer :phrase_id
          t.integer :synonym_id, foreign_key: { references: :phrases }

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

After database drop and migrate the schema was generated correctly.

```
    # db/schema.rb
    -    t.foreign_key ["synonym_id"], "synonyms", ["id"], :on_update => :no_action, :on_delete => :no_action, :name => "fk_synonyms_synonym_id"
    +    t.foreign_key ["synonym_id"], "phrases", ["id"], :on_update => :no_action, :on_delete => :no_action, :name => "fk_synonyms_synonym_id"
```

I'm curious is there a way of setting this relationship without editing the migration files? Maybe some other naming convention in models? Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, database-level foreign keys have been introduced in yet unreleased [Rails 4.2](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support). For now, most use simple associations, naming conventions for these are outlined [in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thx for reply, after analyzing that, it became clear that possible naming convention in generating database-level foreign keys should be handled by this gem I've used, schema_plus.

Comment: I guess for Rails 4.2+ (I'm thinking of the future) this gem is obsolete.

Comment: I tried without schema_plus gem. There is still a need to modify migration files, but seems like more straightforward.

`add_foreign_key :synonyms, :phrases, column: :synonym_id`

(does not support sqlite, only pg and mysql)